# Alternate proof that Chermak-Delgado subgroup of a finite group is characteristic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was revisiting group theory in detail and reading Isaacs's Finite Group Theory book in my own time. I came to know that the Chermak-Delgado subgroup of a finite group $G$ is characteristic in $G$. The definition/construction of the Chermak-Delgado subgroup can be found in Section 1G of Isaacs's book.

The way it is proved in Theorem 1.41 (along with Corollary 1.45) in the book is by showing that the Chermak-Delgado subgroup is "unique" by virtue of lattice structure.

> I want to know if there is an alternate proof (maybe more "direct") of the fact that the Chermak-Delgado subgroup of a finite group $G$ is characteristic.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If it exists then it is clearly characteristic, so you are really asking for a direct proof that it exists?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Possibly I am missing something, sorry, but if exists then why it should be characteristic?

Comment: Because any image of it under an automorphism has the same order, and the centralizer has the same order. So it must also be the CD subgroup.

Comment: It's also unique because the intersection of two subgroups with the CD property has the CD property. In what sense do you want a direct construction? Some finite groups have trivial CD subgroup, for example,

Comment: @DavidA.Craven this makes more sense now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any Automorphism respects subgroup order and so, if $\phi\in\text{Aut}(G)$ and $M$ is the Chermak-Delgado subgroup, then $|\phi(M)|=|M|$ and $|C_G(\phi(M))|=|C_G(M)|$ as $\phi$ respects the group-structure.
It follows that $m_G(\phi(M))=m_G(M)$, meaning that $\phi(M)$ is also in the Chermak-Delgado lattice.
Now $M$ has the lowest order in the entire lattice, as, if there were some $N$ in the CD-lattice with $N\neq M$ and $|N|=|M|$, then $N\cap M$ would be a new minimum in the lattice.
So $M$ is unique in its order and thus $\phi(M)=M$.